# How to Make a Tkinter Button Visually Respond to a Key Press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm using Python with Tkinter, and I have a button that I want to be visually pressed when I hit the Enter key. Here's how I'm initializing the button:

```
self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.gameframe, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.set_input(None)) 
self.submit_button.pack()
```

I've tried using `invoke` to make the button appear pressed, but it's not working as expected. I've also bound the Enter key to the button's functionality with:

```
self.root.bind('', self.set_input) and self.gameframe.pack(fill='both')
```

Is there a better way to make the button look pressed when I press Enter key, or should I modify my code in a specific way to achieve this?